# Does the isolation forest care about integer-encoded categorical variables?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, random-forest, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

The **isolation forest** ([initial paper](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf), [follow-up paper](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/tkdd11.pdf)) as well as the proposed **extended** isolation forest ([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.02141.pdf)) seem like very appealing unsupervised anomaly detection techniques. However, the algorithms themselves work solely on continuous numerical data and cannot incorporate categorical (nominal) variables.

Since lot of machine learning models work with distance or density metrics, a simple mapping of nominal categorical variables to unique integers (i.e. 'A'-->0, 'B'-->1, ..., 'XYZAB'-->1022) would be a cardinal mistake as the models will impose a false sense of originality (e.g. implying 23 > 7 where 23 and 7 are simply different unrelated categories).

**However, does the isolation forest care about such simple mappings of categorical variables to unique integers?** (e.g. using [scikit-learn's LabelEncoder class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html))

Since no computation of density or distance metrics are involved in the calculation of the anomaly score, I believe this is a valid question to discuss. It is not obvious to me why the model should not simply work with such a simple encoding of categorical variables, provided for example when the isolation trees are fully grown.